# Escape regex string for sed in windows cmd in FOR loop

Tags: sed, cmd, escaping

I have a `sed` command, which, when issued on its own, grabs exactly the piece which it shoulds:

```
sed -r -n 's/^.+new_ldap_user.+authenticity_token.+value="([^"]+).+/\1/p' response.html
```

So far so good. Now when I try to put this piece into a `FOR` loop to store the result from `sed` in a variable I have no clue how to escape the several quotes / brackets properly.

What I have tried:

```
FOR /F %i IN ('sed -r -n ^'s/^.+new_ldap_user.+authenticity_token.+value="([^"]+).+/\1/p^' response.html') DO set AUTH=%i
```

> .+/\1/p' was unexpected at this time.

So it seems to me that I also have to escape the closing bracket:

```
FOR /F %i IN ('sed -r -n ^'s/^.+new_ldap_user.+authenticity_token.+value="([^"]+^).+/\1/p^' response.html') DO set AUTH=%i
```

This code does at least not result in an error, but it does not result in `AUTH` to be set properly either.

I tried to double all carets `^` within the `regex` as well, but to no avail.

How do I need to properly escape my `sed` subcommand to be able to store it results in `AUTH`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit tricky, because the caret is used in the batch file itself, and later it's used again in the sub-cmd instance.

It's easier to store the command into a variable and delay the expansion into the child instance, then the caret has to be escaped only once and the parenthesis don't need any escapes.

```
@echo off

set "cmd=sed -r -n 's/^^.+new_ldap_user.+authenticity_token.+value="([^^"]+).+/\1/p' response.html"

FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ('"%%cmd%%"') DO (
    echo ## %%i
)
```

#### command line context

This is a bit more tricky, because the late percent expansion of `%%cmd%%` doesn't work here.

But you can simulate it with

```
FOR /F "delims=" %i in ('^"%^cmd%^"') DO echo %i
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected when I put it into a `.bat` file. Any idea how I can run that in an interactive session? I replaced all `%%` by `%` but I get still the same error as before..

Comment: Works like a charm! Thx +1